# Custom Notification Manager

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't remove my app notification from notification bar by sliding/swiping or with default "clear all" option in android.
I got `.setAutoCancel(true)` in code as well.
But it seems that doesn't work.
anyway to make it removable by swiping like I can do on other app notification. Mine just stuck there.
I know the `cancel()` and `cancelAll()`, and giving an intent method to remove by touch (from other stackflow posts).

Answer (score 0):

I just found an help in another stackflow post..(was opposite of my requirement).
For me, I needed to make `false` in ongoing

```
nBuilder.setOngoing(false);
```

where, nBuilder is my Notification.builder